# Why does REST web service called REST

Tags: rest

What does "Representational state transfer" means , that the current REST web services is called so?

Comment: What? I don't understand your question.

Comment: I mean the words "Representational state transfer",, what they have to do with web service ??

Comment: Nothing. You *can* do REST via HTTP and web but it's not necessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What exactly is RESTful programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming)

Answer (score 11):

One of the best explanations for REST is [How to GET a Cup of Coffee](http://www.infoq.com/articles/webber-rest-workflow).

**Edit:** It is called REST, because the client initiates transfer of representations of client state.

Comment: you should mean "the client initiates transfer of representations of server state."

Comment: @johnG Could you elaborate, Which would be more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer said

> REpresentational State Transfer (REST) is a style of software
>   architecture for distributed systems such as the World Wide Web. REST
>   has emerged as a predominant Web service design model.

---

A RESTful web service (also called a RESTful web API) is a web service implemented **using HTTP and the principles of REST**. It is a collection of resources, with four defined aspects:

1. the base URI for the web service, such as http://example.com/resources/
2. the Internet media type of the data supported by the web service.
   This is often XML but can be any other valid Internet media type
   providing that it is a valid hypertext standard.
3. the set of operations supported by the web service using HTTP
   methods (e.g., GET, PUT, POST, or DELETE).
4. The API must be hypertext driven.